# Why do China and Pakistan have such a strong bond?

Tags: international-relations, china, pakistan

China has often come to the aid of Pakistan when it requires any diplomatic support in the world arena.

Why do China and Pakistan share a strong relationship?

Comment: If you look to the right side of the page, you will see the "Related" section which lots of questions about the relationships between China and Pakistan...

Comment: I want to know the history, behind the support @SJuan76

Comment: Hi @Arka_Dev can you name your sources where you found the information? Also, China is a big issue. Do you mean they supporting as economic or politic influence?

Comment: Please include some examples or references that show China is supporting Pakistan. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Related question: [What would be the impact of CPEC on Pakistan?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/what-would-be-the-impact-of-cpec-on-pakistan)

Comment: You have provided no evidence that Pakistan is associated with this decision.  I have edited the question into something more useful and ontopic.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask something entirely different than it was asking before, especially when it already received an answer. Ask a completely new question instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "Cornered by all other countries", as far as I am aware, no other country except Afghanistan and Bangladesh jumped on Moodi's bandwagon to isolate Pakistan? Not to mention, India has openly admitted supporting the rebels/terrorists in Baluchistan so I don't think anyone is innocent anywhere.

Comment: I would question the premise that China and Pakistan have a particularly strong bond. While they are allies, there is not really the kind of "special relationship" that the UK and US used to have, for example.

Answer (score 5):

**Dispute of Johnson Line and Aksai Chin (1865):** India and China both demands Aksai Chin to be the part of their territory.

**McMohan Line (1914):** China rejected some parts of McMohan line, especially the border between Tibet and Arunachal, which demarks the border between India and China proposed by British rulers.

**Status of Tibet and Asylum of Dalai Lama (1959):** India protested the occupation of Tibet by China. During the conflict between China and Tibet, India gave asylum to the fleeing Tibetan religious leader Dalai Lama who still lives in India.

**Sino-Indian War (1962):** Due to border disputes (McMahon Line) and the dispute about the possession of Aksai Chin, China fought a war with India and India lost the war miserably.

**Sino-Pakistan Agreement (1963):** Seeing India in conflict with China, Pakistan decided to establish a strong relationship by ceding those lands to China which are demanded by both China and India. Thereby, Pakistan ceded 5,180 sqkm of land which is part of Northern Kashmir and Ladakh and China ceded 1942 sqkm of land to Pakistan which resulted in the end of the land dispute between China and Pakistan once and for all. The land that Pakistan handed to China, is now disputed between India and China.

**Permanent membership of China in the UNSC (1971):** Pakistan was the broker behind the secret visit of Henry Kissinger to China during the 1970s, collected votes from the Arab world in favor of China, and thereby paved the way for China to become a permanent member of the UNSC.

**American embargo on defense-products:** USA sanctioned Pakistan during the early 80's for its nuclear program. The USA withheld both the downpayment money and the supply of 36 F-16 planes. China was sanctioned during the late 80's for the crackdown on civilian protestors in Tien-an-men square. These two sanctions opened the gate for defense cooperation between these two victims in those areas which were rare. For instance, aerospace, nuclear, and so on.

**Neo Indo-US alliance:** Between India and China, the USA preferred India to form an alliance with. There are several reasons behind that,

1. China is a semi-communist country which is run by a single-party, while India is a multi-party democracy. So, it's not easy to manipulate Chinese government.
2. China isn't submissive to US hegemony, and they proved that times and again.
3. India is not technologically self-reliant, while, to some extent, China is, and they are striving very hard to close the gap (India is also trying, but, is suffering from low-quality education, and living standard. As a result, India is experiencing a lot of human capital flight).

This alliance has made the life of Pakistan very difficult. Because,

1. India is continuously purchasing arms from the USA, which Pakistan either can't afford or, the USA won't sell. This is shifting the balance of power in favor of India by such a distance, that Pakistan won't be able to catch up.
2. The USA is encouraging India presence in Afghanistan where India is able to influence Afghan government and wage a proxy war against Pakistan. They are also allegedly financing Afghan-based terrorist groups to act against Pakistan.

This has encouraged the Sino-Pak alliance, and more.

Answer (score 3):

No one is likely to give a firm answer since China doesn't normally publicize its internal deliberations.  But a few educated cases would note that (remembering that India and Pakistan are enemies):

- China has a poor relationship with India. [They have an ongoing border dispute that China has recently been pushing.](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/war/india-china_conflicts.htm)
- China has a poor relationship with India. [China doesn't like how India has supported the Dalai Lama](http://www.cnn.com/2009/WORLD/asiapcf/03/31/dalai.lama/)
- When you say "other countries have Pakistan cornered" I'm not sure what you mean, but China tends to resist strongly the idea that countries should be governed by international norms particularly when those norms could be interpreted as interfering in the internal affairs of a nation.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened. Pakistan behaved like a friend even before China was big deal. Its unwitting, friendly behaviour was rather spontaneous and unconditional without any calculation. When China was weak and humble and was the pariah of the world, Pakistan was the only fool who lent China a hand. For a long time, Pakistan was the only conduit through which China communicated with the outside world. When Sino-American relation began to thaw, it was Pakistan who funnelled friends China's way and eventually promoted peace between two arch-rivals.

In a sea of people, how do you tell who is your friend?

1. He who gives you a hand when you are in dire need of help.
2. He who helps you make friends instead of turning people against you.

In plain English, Pakistan, in the Chinese eye, is a proverbial friend.